# Quartus netlist optimization lost register fanout in a state machine

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, quartus

Hi guys i'm trying to implement a state machine but i have the problem that during timing simulation i get an error saying that

> Info: 1 registers lost all their fanouts during netlist optimizations. The first 1 are displayed below.

> Info: Register "state.STATE_I" lost all its fanouts during netlist optimizations.

and in the waveform timing simulation the output works fine but if i try to check the actual state I only get an initial state (STATE I) and an "UNDEFINED" in the rest of places where the actual state should be shown, the code is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--define entity
entity pregunta1a is
  port(
    resetn  : in  std_logic;
    clock   : in  std_logic;
    w       : in  std_logic;
    z       : out std_logic
  );
end pregunta1a;
--define architecture
architecture behavior of pregunta1a is
  type STATE_TYPE is (STATE_A,STATE_B,STATE_C,STATE_D,STATE_E,STATE_F,STATE_I); -- todos los estados
  signal state, next_state : STATE_TYPE;
begin
  process(clock)
  begin
    if(rising_edge(clock)) then
      if (resetn='0') then
        state <= STATE_I;                
      else
        state <= next_state;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  
  process(state,w) -- complete sensitivity list
  begin
    z<='0';
    case state is
      when  STATE_A =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_B;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_C;
        end if;
      when STATE_B =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_D;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        end if;
      when STATE_C =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_B;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
        end if;
      when STATE_D =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_F;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        end if;
      when STATE_E =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_B;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
          z<='1';  
        end if;
      when STATE_F =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_F;
          z<='1';        
        else
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        end if;
      when STATE_I =>
        if (w = '1') then
          next_state <= STATE_B;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        end if;
    end case;
  end process; 
end behavior;
```

[This is a screenshot of the timing simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjL0s.png)
anyone known how to solve this ??

Comment: Your [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N487j.jpg) doesn't match your waveform. (Note the synchronous reset and the default value for state - the left value of STATE_TYPE, STATE_A). Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i´ve found a solution to my problem, it seems that i have to force some type of interaction with the register lost (state_I). I've changed some parts of the code and ordered it to make things more clear:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--define entity
entity pregunta1a is
  port(
    resetn  : in  std_logic;
    clock   : in  std_logic;
    w       : in  std_logic;
    z       : out std_logic
  );
end pregunta1a;
--define architecture
architecture behavior of pregunta1a is
  type STATE_TYPE is (STATE_A,STATE_B,STATE_C,STATE_E,STATE_F,STATE_G,STATE_R); -- todos los estados
  signal state, next_state : STATE_TYPE:=state_R;
begin
  process(clock)
  begin
    if(rising_edge(clock)) then
      if (resetn='0') then
        state <= STATE_R;                
      else
        state <= next_state;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  
  process(state,w,resetn) -- complete sensitivity list
  begin
    z<='0';
    next_state<=state_R;
    case state is
      when  STATE_A =>
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_B;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
        end if;
      when STATE_B =>
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_C;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
        end if;
      when STATE_C =>
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_C;
          z<='1';
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
        end if;
      when STATE_E =>
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_F;
        end if;
      when STATE_F =>
        
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_G;
        end if;
      when STATE_G =>
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_G;
          z<='1';        
        end if;
      when STATE_R =>
        if(resetn='1') then
        if (w = '0') then
          next_state <= STATE_A;
        else
          next_state <= STATE_E;
        end if;
        else
          next_state<=state_R;
        end if;
    end case;
    
  end process; 
end behavior;
```

it seems that i have to force some type of interaction to establish STATE_I, the programs was working as it was, but one of the requirements was to get rid of this problem in the simulation